# How to make perl handle pattern "c++" same as grep?

Tags: regex, perl, error-handling, grep

This isn't surprising:

```
% perl -ne 'print if /c++/' foo
Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/c++ <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

But this is, kinda:

```
% grep c++ foo
blah c++ blah
```

I don't know what grep is doing to accommodate the `++` -- but I'd like the same in perl.  Or, at least, some graceful way of dealing with this situation; the pattern comes from a user, who might see that `grep c++` works and then is surprised by the failure in perl.

I don't want to use `quotemeta`; my real code expects regex patterns (from a user):

```
while ( my $pattern = shift @pat_list ) {
    my $regex = $opts{case} ? qr/$pattern/ : qr/$pattern/i;
    my @hits = grep { /$regex/ } @lines;
```

I think I would be OK with detecting that the pattern has an error and then reverting to `quotemeta`.  But I can't seem to use `eval` to trap the error (because it's seen as a syntax error?).

Comment: I don't see any simple way of predicting every failing regex, you may have to require users to escape their regex, otherwise it's ambiguous

Comment: How do you expect perl to be able to tell the difference between intended and unintended meta characters?

Comment: What exactly do you want to support in the regular expression pattern input?  I'm not sure why you would want to use `grep`'s syntax instead of `perl`'s (or `egrep`'s, for that matter, which is much closer to `perl` than regular `grep`, and gives a similar error for the `c++` example: `egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid`).  

Different tools have different regular expression syntax, and assuming that something that works in `grep` will work in anything that's *not* `grep` is just not a valid assumption, nor one you should be encouraging in your users.

Comment: "my real code expects regex patterns (from a user)" and you desire to have `c++` match `c++` are in direct contradiction with each other. Which one do you want???

Comment: Note that `c++` is a valid pattern in anything but ancient versions of Perl. Note that falling back doesn't work if you want `c+` to match `c+`.

Comment: So I'm guessing 5.8.3 is ancient?

Comment: I didn't ask a very good question.  So I'm going to ask a new question, and hope that this one gets appropriately dismissed.

Comment: @JohnH. You can edit your question to make it better. Or delete it if you think it cannot be salvaged.

Answer (score 4):

The shell command `grep` knows at least three modes for how it interpretes regular expressions: as basic REs (default), as extended REs (if invoked with `-E` or as `egrep`) and Perl-compatible REs (if invoked with `-P`). Basic REs behave quite a bit differently for someone used to Perl's RE engine. `grep`'s documentation says about your particular use case:

```
In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose
their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(,
and \).
```

This means that there is no meta character in the call to `grep c++ something.txt`.

Note that even the Perl-compatible REs (provided by the well-known library `libpcre`) are not identical to what Perl's own RE engine implements. Perl's engine's feature set is pretty unique amongst all RE implementations out there. But PCRE (Perl-compatible REs) from libpcre are at least pretty similar and also used widely, e.g. in PHP, C++ (Boost), tools like `grep` and most like a lot of other programming languages.

Having said that: I suggest that if you want to use most REs in both Perl and with `grep` then use `grep`'s Perl-compatible mode, e.g. `grep --perl-regexp $yourRE $yourFile.txt`. Also make sure to take care of shell quoting if you allow arbitrary user input! There's [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.04/ShellQuote.pm) for that.

Comment: This makes sense, but unfortunately doesn't help: `grep -E c++ foo` also works, as does `grep 'c**' foo`.

Comment: If you accept input directly from a user then you have to enforce some rules what kinds of input are valid and which are not. This should be documented (command line help output, man page, extra document, whatever). You cannot hope to accept anything a user throws at you and hope for the best as people have different experience and background. Some know grep REs, some know Perl REs, some even come from Emacs (even more subtle differences).

Answer (score 1):

If you want grep-compatible (POSIX) regex, you can use [POSIX::Regex](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/POSIX-Regex-1.0001/). (It is not a standard module, you may need to install it with cpan command.)

Answer (score 0):

The main point of my question is wrong.  This works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $pattern = "c++";
my $regex;
eval { $regex = qr/$pattern/; };
warn "Error detected: $@" if $@;
```

I have requested that my question be deleted.  Sorry to have wasted y'all's time.

Answer (score 0):

perl -ne 'print if /c\+\+/' foo

In regex '+' mean 'one or more'.